# how to get data in _afterSave function in model

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, order-status

I am creating a custom model and rewriting the `sales/order_status` model and create the function

```
public function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object){

    echo "here"; exit;
}
```

this function is executing perfectly but i want to get data. how can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

better using `$this` instead of `$object`, try it like `Mage::log($this->_getEventData(), null, 'debug.log', true)`

Answer (score 2):

use the `$object` variable.
Use `Mage::log($object->getData(), null, 'debug.log', true)` to see what values you have available and then use what ever you need.

**[EDIT]**
The code above works if you rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Status` class

For `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status` your method should look like this:

```
public function _afterSave()
{
    Mage::log($this->getData(), null, 'debug.log', true);
    parent::_afterSave();
}
```

Again, you should see in `var/log/debug.log` the values you have available.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getData()

Comment: wait...are you rewriteing `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status` or  `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Status` ?

Comment: Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status

Comment: i tried it before but get the same error..

Comment: @QaisarSatti. See my update.

Comment: thanks bro but i already find the solution thanks a lot :)